Why declare the function as async when the other function inside the function block is itself an asynchronous function
const fs = require('fs').promises

const filePath = './me.txt';
async function  readFileAsync(){
 try{
    const data=  await fs.readFile(filePath,'utf-8')
    console.log(data)
 }
 catch(err){
    console.log(err)
 }

}
readFileAsync()

taking the above code as an example.We know fs.readFile() is an async function and returns a promise and await will return the resolved value of the promise.Then why do we need to declare the readFileAsync with the async keyword?

Have you tried what happens when you don't declare readFileAsync as asnyc?

Yes! I mean to ask if is it just for the sake of syntax?

Yes, it is necessary for using the await syntax.

The async keyword on the function enables using the await keyword within the function execution, which stops executing the rest of the function until the promise of readFile function gets resolved, and for sure it makes the readFileAsync function asynchronous for the same reason.

So is it just for syntax purpose?
